# CR/LF as line terminator in Synapse data flow using delimited text as a sink

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am using a data flow in Synapse, the sink is Delimited text.  I have to provide the output to a system that expects CR/LF (\r\n) as the row terminator.

**Default (\r,\n, or \r\n)**

returns \n (LF) only as the row terminator in all of my tests.  Has anyone had this requirement and found a work around?

Comment: please provide some information about source?

Answer (score 0):

In `DataFlow mapping` for separating rows in Delimited text format there are certain default values:

- **To Read from file: "\r\n", "\r," or "\n"**
- **To Write in file: "\n"**

To workaround try by manually adding in dataflow script and running the pipeline.

```json
rowDelimiter: '\r\n'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying, when add that line 

**rowDelimeter: '\r\n'**

it saves ok and the flow looks fine, but when I go back and hit the {} to view the script again I see

**rowDelimeter: '\r'**

Comment: as per [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-delimited-text#dataset-properties) **"\r\n" is only supported in copy command.**

Answer (score 0):

[pratiklad] (https://stackoverflow.com/users/18043699/pratiklad) has it right.  As odd as it sounds CR/LF is not supported in data flow in sink.  Seems the best I can do, if I am using a data flow, is to out to my storage account, then use copy activity to open the file and re-write it adding the CR/LF (\r\n).

Comment: You can leave that as a comment to the answer you got.

Answer (score 0):

You can concat a '\r' on the last column of your dataset and then it will read \r\n on the text or csv files.